# Android-res-string.xml Проблема кодировки

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Случилась проблема с кодировкой. В дизайнере во вкладке TextViec (text), если я указываю на ресурс текста, который находится в res_string.xml после запуска приложения русский текст вообще не отображается, с английским проблем нету.
Если же не выбирать ресурс а просто написать в text "Привет", то отобразится без проблем. Не подскажете, может что нужно дописать?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">TestApplication</string>
    <string name="btn_text">Ответить!</string>
    <string name="Hello_world">Как дела ?</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Покажите-ка как вы обращаетесь к строковому ресурсу

Comment: Указываю в дизайнере в поле TextView - text - @string/Hello_world

Answer (score 0):

Если вы разделили языки в Ресурсах, проверьте какой язык у вас по умолчанию на устройстве. Возможно английский, тогда система автоматически подтягивает Ресурсы по умолчанию, на английском.

[О поддержке различных языков](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).

Comment: Да, я пытался создавать специальные ресурсы с локализацией.
Однако видел, что люди используют по умолчанию ресурс отображается, вот и не понимаю в чём у меня беда =\

Comment: у вас сколько папок `values` в папке `res`?

Comment: Когда пытался с локализацией было 2
values-ru и values
А теперь одна, просто не понимаю, где нужно ему прописать что бы отображал символы

Comment: Вас выше спросили, как вы обращаетесь к ресурсу. Дополните свой вопрос фрагментом кода с обращением к строке.

Comment: tools:text="@string/Hello_world" (Вот идёт обращение)
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Privetstvie"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"

Comment: это у вас .xml, в Активити у вас есть `TextView textPrivetstvie = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Privetstvie);` ?

Comment: Почитайте [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/android2.php), возможно вы в корне не представляете как выводить текст

Comment: Нет...в моём активити я не использую TextViev и прочие с ним методы.
С ним проблем не возникает.
Сейчас ещё потестив, заметил такую вещь, если задавать ресурсы через android:text="@string/Hello_world", то отображается, однако по умолчанию он создавал tools:text="@string/Hello_world"
Просто получается, это каждый раз нужно менять вручную в .xml файле.